# Angular 4 OverlayContainer duplicate

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material, overlay

In my project I'm using [md2 components](https://github.com/Promact/md2) and [angular material dialog component](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).
After running my code in my browser, when I open a [md2-select](https://github.com/Promact/md2/tree/master/src/lib/select) or a [md2-datepicker](https://github.com/Promact/md2/tree/master/src/lib/datepicker), it adds a `cdk-overlay-container` div to the page's `body`:

```
<div class="cdk-overlay-container"></div>
```

Every time I use an md2 component which needs an overlay, it uses the existing one. This is the normal behavior.
My problem comes when I open a material dialog once this first md2 `OverlayContainer` is created. Instead of using the existing `OverlayContainer`, the material dialog create a new one. It causes some problems with z-index. Why material dialog doesn't uses the existing `OverlayContainer`?
When I take a look at the [`OverlayContainer` code](https://github.com/Promact/md2/blob/master/src/lib/core/overlay/overlay-container.ts), I can see this comment:

```
/**
 * The OverlayContainer is the container in which all overlays will load.
 * It should be provided in the root component to ensure it is properly shared.
 */
```

How can I provide this container to the root component to ensure to have only one `OverlayContainer`?

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you just have to detach/dispose the things you no longer need

```
const overlayRef = this.overlay.create({....});
.... some other code            
let componentRef = overlayRef.attach(yourcomponent);

Once you're done
componentRef.destroy();

overlayRef.detach();
overlayRef.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create your own implementation of the overlay container, extending the `OverlayContainer` and provide it on the appModule. For example, you may want to attach the overlay to a specific component instead of appending the overlay to the `<body>`.

This resolved answer from @Marshal open my eyes, creating a nice directive to control that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55289312/6852402

Also, you will like to take a look on this solution from Bogdan Bogdanov: https://blog.bbogdanov.net/post/angular-material-overlay-hack-overlay-container/

Have fun!