# Angular CDK Overlay, change default overlay container

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

Is there a way to change the OverlayContainer?

I have created a tooltip component, but sometimes I want to attach the overlay to a specific element (by default the overlay is attached to the document body).

Here is how I am creating the overlay:

```
  private initOverlay(): void {
    const positionStrategy = this.overlayPositionBuilder
      .flexibleConnectedTo(this.elementRef)
      .withPositions([this.resolvedConfig]);

    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({positionStrategy});
  }
```

And this is how I am attaching a template to it:

```
  show(): void {
    this.overlayRef.attach(new TemplatePortal(this.tpl, this.viewContainerRef));
  }
```

Comment: What's your use case for attaching it to a specific element?

Comment: I have a dialog, the tooltip appears behind it (the tooltip trigger is placed on the dialog).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please reference this stackblitz example.

> looks like you can accomplish this by extending the
>   `OverlayContainer` class via the following in `app.module.ts`

`{ provide: OverlayContainer, useFactory: () => new AppOverlayContainer() }`

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ansnt5?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

---

This GitHub comment also provides an example of how to package this in a `directive`

**GitHub comment**

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7349#issuecomment-337513040

---

**Revision 3/22/19 working directive example**

Extend the `OverlayContainer` class via `cdk-overlay-container.ts`

Stub the class in `app.module.ts`

```
  providers: [
    { provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: CdkOverlayContainer },
  ]
```

In your `cdk-overlay-container.ts` you are preventing the default `_createContainer()` from working, and providing your own custom public method `myCreateContainer` to replace it.

> You are essentially creating an empty `div` here, adding a custom class to it `my-custom-overlay-container-class` and appending it to the
>   `div` the directive is attached to, then passing that container to the
>   private variable `_containerElement` in the true `OverlayContainer`
>   class.

```
/**
* Create overlay container and append to ElementRef from directive
*/ 
public myCreateContainer(element: HTMLElement): void {
   let container = document.createElement('div');
   container.classList.add('my-custom-overlay-container-class');

   element.appendChild(container);
   this._containerElement = container;
 }
 /**
  * Prevent creation of the HTML element, use custom method above
  */
 protected _createContainer(): void {
     return;
 }
```

Then in your `cdk-overlay-container.directive.ts` your are calling `myCreateContainer()` and passing the `ElementRef` as an argument.

```
 this.cdkOverlayContainer['myCreateContainer'](this.elementReference.nativeElement);
```

Then in your HTML assign the directive where you want it to show up.

```
<div myCdkOverlayContainer
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-6nzwws?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Yes, I saw this suggestion, the problem with this is that I might need to provide the custom OverlayContainer per each instance of the tooltip directive. 

Seems though there is no other way to achieve this. Would be nice if it would be configurable though.

Comment: Although I believe the directive approach may be a solution here, I am having trouble implementing it in stackblitz. Will update answer if I can get it going.

Comment: Please see revision with directive example.

Comment: In the implementation with `myCdkOverlayContainer` directive, all tooltips are attached to the last overlay container (4th). I am missing something here? I thought that is possible to attach different tooltips to different containers. Thanks.

Comment: The implementation is creating a container on each element to calculate the position of the tooltip. But ultimately, because the `OverlayContainer` class is a singleton, the tooltips will be rendered in the last container created. This example was to control the placement of the tooltip/calculate position.

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: this.cdkOverlayContainer.myCreateContainer is not a function`. I followed your stackblitz example. Any ideas?

Comment: @gyozokudor I had this problem, it's caused by the directive getting an `OverlayContainer` instance rather than your custom class. It was solved by making my custom `OverlayContainer` class `@Injectable()`.